# Vue.js bootsrap pagination not applying styles

Tags: laravel, vue.js, bootstrap-4

I'm currently working on a `Vue.js` component in my `Laravel` application, and I'm stuck on `pagination`. My pagination logic works like a charm, but the `Bootstrap` styles are not applied. This is my `Vue.js` component:

```
<template>
...
   <div style="margin: auto; text-align: center;">
        <pagination v-if="pagination.total > pagination.per_page"
             :pagination="pagination" :callback="loadData"
             :options="paginationOptions">
        </pagination>
   </div>
...
</template>

<script>

import pagination from 'vue-bootstrap-pagination';
export default {
    components: {
        pagination
    },
pagination: {
        total: 0,
        per_page: 15,    // required
        current_page: 1, // required
        last_page: 0,    // required
        from: 1,
        to: 12
    },
    paginationOptions: {
        offset: 4,
        previousText: 'Previous',
        nextText: 'Next',
        alwaysShowPrevNext: true
    },
   ...

  </script>
```

As I said, my pagination works like a charm, but I have no styles to it. This is how it currently looks like:

[image]

Desired output would be something like this: 
[image]

Comment: Are you importing the BootstrapVue CSS files into your `app.js` file per the documentation?  https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs

Comment: I'm not using that exact package. I followed this [tutorial](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-bootstrap-pagination)

Comment: The package you linked is using designed for drop-in use with Bootstrap 3.  You need to load the CSS file separately.

Comment: Looking in the code of the package, it appears to call the same classes as bootstrap 4 for pagination styling even though it was tested with 3. unless I am miss reading something. I would inspect your web page and see if there is a `pagination` class being applied to the component before you move to 3.

Comment: There is `pagination` class being applied to the element from `material-dashboard.css` . I will try to downgrade to `bootstrap 3`, and will let you know if there are any changes

Comment: No changes at all. One more thing, I was using the same package in the other application, and it was working fine there. I just went through the code on the other application, I'm sure I have the same setup

Comment: I have added the `page-item` and `page-link` classes to the package component per the [Bootstrap 4 docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/pagination/).  You can try using this component instead and see if it helps: https://gist.github.com/matticustard/9e11277b2e4f32e8bfffa9a08e38f338

Comment: This almost worked as a charm, it's just sometimes missing the styling on the Previous/Next buttons [image](https://imgur.com/WwWYHNG)

Comment: I updated the Gist above to remove the extra Aria spans from the Previous/Next buttons.  See if that makes it work.

Comment: It works as desired. I can't thank you enough. Please add this as an answer, so I can accept it. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Done.  Happy to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on our conversation above, it seems that the package you are using was written for Bootstrap 3, which has a slightly different pagination scheme.

I have updated the package Vue component with the proper class additions for Bootstrap 4.  You can now use this component directly instead of loading the outdated package.

https://gist.github.com/matticustard/9e11277b2e4f32e8bfffa9a08e38f338

**Pagination.vue**

```html
<template>
    <nav>
        <ul class="pagination" v-if="pagination.last_page > 0" :class="sizeClass">
            <li class="page-item" v-if="showPrevious()" :class="{ 'disabled' : pagination.current_page <= 1 }">
                <a href="#" class="page-link" v-if="pagination.current_page > 1 " :aria-label="config.ariaPrevioius" @click.prevent="changePage(pagination.current_page - 1)">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">{{ config.previousText }}</span>
                </a>
            </li>

            <li class="page-item" v-for="num in array" :class="{ 'active' : num === pagination.current_page }">
                <a href="#" class="page-link" @click.prevent="changePage(num)">{{ num }}</a>
            </li>

            <li class="page-item" v-if="showNext()" :class="{ 'disabled' : pagination.current_page === pagination.last_page || pagination.last_page === 0 }">
                <a href="#" class="page-link" v-if="pagination.current_page < pagination.last_page" :aria-label="config.ariaNext" @click.prevent="changePage(pagination.current_page + 1)">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">{{ config.nextText }}</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    pagination: {
      type: Object,
      required: true,
    },
    callback: {
      type: Function,
      required: true,
    },
    options: {
      type: Object,
    },
    size: {
      type: String,
    },
  },
  computed: {
    array() {
      if (this.pagination.last_page <= 0) {
        return [];
      }
      let from = this.pagination.current_page - this.config.offset;
      if (from < 1) {
        from = 1;
      }
      let to = from + (this.config.offset * 2);
      if (to >= this.pagination.last_page) {
        to = this.pagination.last_page;
      }
      const arr = [];
      while (from <= to) {
        arr.push(from);
        from += 1;
      }
      return arr;
    },
    config() {
      return Object.assign({
        offset: 3,
        ariaPrevious: 'Previous',
        ariaNext: 'Next',
        previousText: '«',
        nextText: '»',
        alwaysShowPrevNext: false,
      }, this.options);
    },
    sizeClass() {
      if (this.size === 'large') {
        return 'pagination-lg';
      } else if (this.size === 'small') {
        return 'pagination-sm';
      }
      return '';
    },
  },
  watch: {
    'pagination.per_page'(newVal, oldVal) { // eslint-disable-line
      if (+newVal !== +oldVal) {
        this.callback();
      }
    },
  },
  methods: {
    showPrevious() {
      return this.config.alwaysShowPrevNext || this.pagination.current_page > 1;
    },
    showNext() {
      return this.config.alwaysShowPrevNext ||
          this.pagination.current_page < this.pagination.last_page;
    },
    changePage(page) {
      if (this.pagination.current_page === page) {
        return;
      }
      this.$set(this.pagination, 'current_page', page);
      this.callback();
    },
  },
};
</script>
```